# Counting occurence of each distinct element in a table

Tags: sql, firebird

I am writing a log viewer app in ASP.NET / C#. There is a report window, where it will be possible to check some information about the whole database. One kind of information there I want to display on the screen is the number of times each generator (an entity in my domain, not Firebirds sequence) appears in the table. How do I do that using COUNT ?

Do I have to :

1. Gather the key for each different generator
2. Run one query for each generator key using count
3. Display it somehow

Is there any way that I can do it without having to do two queries to the database?  The database size can be HUGE, and having to query it "X" times where "X" is the number of generators would just suck.

I am using a Firebird database, is there any way to fetch this information from any metadata schema or there is no such thing available?

Basically, what I want is to count each occurrence of each generator in the table. Result would be something like : GENERATOR A:10 times,GENERATOR B:7 Times,Generator C:0 Times and so on.

Comment: What do you mean with `generator`? Do you mean Firebird generators (aka sequences), or is this some entity from your domain?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel GENERATOR is an Entity from my domain,sorry for not providing such information

Comment: I don't really understand what your trying to do, but why not run the query from stage "2" with a group by clause (grouping for generator key)?

Comment: @A.B.Cade i am no SQL Master,not event close to that.
I will see what i can do with Group By,since i´ve never used it :/

Basically,what i want,is to count each occurence of each Generator in the table.

Resulting is something like : GENERATOR A : 10 times,GENERATOR B : 7 Times,Generator C : 0 Times and so on.

Comment: Thanks @A.B.Cade for the reply about group by.

I solved my problem using this simple Query:

    SELECT GENERATOR_,count(*)
    FROM EVENTSGENERAL
    GROUP BY GENERATOR_;

Thanks again. Problem,solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the query below should be sufficient (depending on your exact structure and requirements)

```
SELECT KEY, COUNT(*)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY KEY
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it is a simple matter of using the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause, e.g.:

```
select
  key,
  count(*)
from generators
group by key;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this simple Query:

```
SELECT GENERATOR_,count(*) 
FROM EVENTSGENERAL GROUP BY GENERATOR_;
```

Thanks for those who helped me.
It took me 8 hours to come back and post the answer,because of the StackOverflow limitation to answer my own questions based in my reputation.